# retrieving character from string.length() , using a FOR statement

Tags: java

I am implementing the Luhn algorithm using a for statement and a string.

My question is, does "j" get assigned the value of the character at that location of the string(the digit), or does it get assigned the value of its numerical location in the string length?

Thank you

*apologize if I am not supposed to paste code directly into this

*EDIT: I am pretty sure it is not actually retrieving the characters but rather only its numerical position in the string, researching char method

---

```
    if (card.length() < 13 || card.length() > 16)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid credit card number");
         card = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the credit card number.");
        num = Long.parseLong(card);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < card.length(); j++) {
        sum = sum + j*2;
        if ( j%2 != 0 ) {
         product = j * 1;
         sum += product;
        }
         else {
             product = j * 2;
         }
         if (product > 9) {
             product -= 9;
         sum += product;
         }
    }
```

Comment: `j` is an `int`, it is acting as an index value.  So, it is not assigned the "character" value and is independent of the `String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `for` statement

```
for (int j = 0; j < card.length(); j++) {
```

It declares and initializes a variable `j` with the value 0. It increments the value of `j` by one on each iteration with the `j++` expression. It does this while the value of `j` is smaller than the value of `card.length()`.

Answer (score 0):

it's the number of the position. `card.length()` returns an int, so `j` will get that value ("the position").

Try the following example to see the difference:

```
    String s = "Hello World";

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        System.out.println("        Value of i: " + i);
        System.out.println("   Value of i in s: " + s.charAt(i));
        System.out.println("Value of i as char: " + (char)i);
        System.out.println("---");
    }
```

first 3 iterations:

```
        Value of i: 0
   Value of i in s: H
Value of i as char: NUL**
---
        Value of i: 1
   Value of i in s: e
Value of i as char: SOH**
---
        Value of i: 2
   Value of i in s: l
Value of i as char: STX**
```

** The char value is not visible, you could look it up here: http://ascii.cl/
If `i` would reach 33 - it would become readable, starting with `!`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code "j" is just the position and will get the values:
0,1,2,3,4.... up to string length.

What you want it the number that the character at that position represents so character "0" (which has value x"30") needs to be converted to an integer with value +0, char "9" (x'39') needs to be converted to an integer value +9.

You can do either:

```
int cval = Integer.parseInt(card.charAt(j));
```

Or the quick and dirty :

```
int cval = card.charAt(j) - 30;
```

The first method will throw an exception when you give it an non-numeric character, the, second will subtract 30 from anything it gets (which code be a a really high value unicode char) so use this method only if you are completly sure the string will contain only ASCII characters 0123456789.